# About RenderScript

Tags: android, scripting, 3d, renderscript

Recently,i search for articles about renderscript,but it seems that there's none. can any one give me some articles talking about renderscript?

Answer (score 15):

Resources, documentation, and tutorials for Renderscript are still pretty scarce.  Here are the places I've found.

**Introduction to Renderscript: parts 1 & 2 (Android Blogs)**

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/introducing-renderscript.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/renderscript.html

**Main Overview (Android Docs)**

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html

**Android JavaDocs (Android Docs)**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/package-summary.html

**Renderscript Runtime API Reference**

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/reference.html

**Examples and some API documentation**

http://code.google.com/p/renderscript-examples/

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/RenderScript/index.html

**Videos**

Learn about RenderScript | 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jz0kSuR2j4

Android Renderscript (LLVM) | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7TqTnlYAg8E

**Blog articles**

http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/11/android-renderscript-more-info-and.html

http://blog.garritys.org/2011/05/getting-started-with-renderscript.html

http://www.independent-software.com/setting-up-android-renderscript-in-android-studio-1-3/

Answer (score 2):

Here is one: [Android renderscript, more info' and an example application](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/11/android-renderscript-more-info-and.html)

Answer (score 1):

Google has now published an [article about RenderScript](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/introducing-renderscript.html), which is a public API in Honeycomb. Still quite sparse on info, but they'll publish more.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the article [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/renderscript.html)
which is from Google development. And There are a lot of examples in `sdk\sample\android-11。`