# Android renderscript documentation

Tags: android, renderscript

I am starting getting to know android renderscript and i've read everything that is on the android developer site, but it seems that there is not enough documentation, examples.. I was wondering if there is maybe a book that also has a part with explanation and some renderscript examples. I want to learn about it in depth, so if someone can provide links for books, examples, tutorials (anything would be of great help) i will appreciate it. Thank u in advance!!!

Comment: This question has been asked <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402871/about-the-renderscript">here</a>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are working on this documentation gap and plan to have updated docs within the next few weeks; however, it will still be a work in progress. If you have specific things that you want to do, let us know. In the meantime, there are samples packaged with the SDK that might help you get started: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/RenderScript/index.html

Comment: Thank u for your response. I am really eager to know more about renderscript and use it in applications. If you can, let me know about the docs updates. Tnx!

Comment: HI, just to update you guys. We are obviously very busy, but I plan on getting updated docs out very soon. What sort of supplemental materials is everyone interested in. The dev guide will still be somewhat too advanced I think for beginners, so I'd like to supplement that with maybe an Android U class. Let me know your thoughts

Comment: The Renderscript docs have been updated and the runtime C99 API reference is also published now.

Comment: Hi Robertly, Can you please post the link? I still cannot find the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I've posted a couple of [RenderScript articles/tutorials on my blog](http://blog.iangclifton.com/tag/renderscript/).  If they're of use, let me know.  I've been debating whether I should make more, but it's tough to gauge interest in RenderScript.

Comment: For a beginner like me, your tutorials have been a lot useful. If you could keep up the work, and maybe provide some more examples, maybe more complicated. Currently I am looking the carousel example source code, because I need to implement sth similar, but its way more complicated than anything else I've seen.

Comment: Also you could do a little bit more explanation of the OpenGl concepts. And maybe try to explain sth like the carousel example, or similar. Thx

Comment: Yeah, the carousel example is a great one, but there is quite a bit to know before it fully makes sense, especially around matrix transformations.  I'll see if I can make the time to do a post on that next.

Comment: Yes, I know. I am trying to get to the bottom of it, and accomplished to use some part of the code but still have some gaps that I need to fill. If you do your next post on this or just maybe the use of matrix transformations, it would be great. Thank u!!

Comment: Sadly Google has totally removed the GUI/3d-related stuff of Renderscript, but can you please put useful tutorial on the "normal" functionality of Renderscript?

Comment: @IanG.Clifton The link to your blog is dead, could you update it in case the material is still out there?

Answer (score 0):

There's very little documentation on Renderscript at this moment in time. Google has published a few posts about it, including the following on the Android Developers Blog, but apart from that, the information available is very limited.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/introducing-renderscript.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/renderscript.html

Some documentation is also available here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html

You can also find some examples here:
http://code.google.com/p/renderscript-examples/

The Android team has promised to add more documentation at some point in time, and I'm hopeful we'll get some more information when Ice Cream Sandwich launches.